# AppleScript to get name of single selected file in finder

Tags: applescript, selection, finder

I want to get the name of the currently in the finder window selected file. I'm working under OS X 10.9.2.

Here's my code:

```
display dialog "test"
tell application "Finder"
  set theItems to selection
  display dialog number of theItems
  repeat with itemRef in theItems
    display dialog name of itemRef
  end repeat
end tell
```

In the Finder I selected only one mp3 file.
If I run the script then the dialogbox with "test" and the dialogbox with "1" is displayed correctly. But then I got the error message that the file cannot be converted into a type string.

I hope you can help me to fix this bug and I thank you in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> file cannot be converted into a type string.

Then convert it to a string.

```
display dialog (name of itemRef) as string
```

---

I'd suggest you to use `log` instead of `display dialog` for debugging purpose.

For instance, `log name of itemRef` will return (in your "Events" and "Replies" window):

> (*name of document file 123.jpg of folder Desktop of
>   folder Saturnix of folder Users of startup disk*)

As you can see, this is much more complex than a simple string of test (like `"123.jpg"`). This is telling you that `name of itemRef` is not returning the actual name of the file `itemRef` but a reference to that name. Luckily enough, calling `as string` on that reference will return us the actual name of the file.

Answer (score 3):

The name property of a file is already a text (or string) type. You are not properly parenthesizing the dialog statement.

```
display dialog (get name of itemRef)
```

Comment: Yes, I have to admit that I've some problems to know when a variable is already a string or only a reference. This dynamic typed language is very new to me. But now I got it to work, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Happy to help. If I have answered you question, accept it so other users know the issue has been resolved.